# JAX-RS Default Servlet

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs, web.xml

i'm developing a REST application. I use Websphere 8.5 and Java EE 6.

I tried to create a REST Web Project with RAD and it defaulted my web.xml with this servlet      Configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
    /jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't want to bind my application configuration with a server specific setting so i would like to use an 'out of the box' servlet of Java EE 6 over `com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet`.

Can you tell me what should i use?

Comment: Do you have any JAX_RS implementation (Jersey, RESTEasy, ...) in your classpath?

Comment: No I don't. But the first thing the Java EE 6 tutorial says about JAX-RS is Jersey is the reference implementation... so o though it is bundled in J2EE. Isn't it?

Comment: No it is not, the implementation for JAXRS need to be added to the application, consider using Jersey

Comment: Ok .. at this point I will use Jersey since it seems to be the reference. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to just reference your Application implementation as a servlet to get the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically JAXRS is just an API, there are several implementation of this API, the most commonly used is Jersey, RESTEasy, CXF, [[comparison]](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/10/jaxrs-comparison), check [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155467/selecting-a-jax-rs-implementation-for-a-new-project)

Add the end you need to consider declare a servlet like this.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            ...
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

This will start loading the Jersey implementation and its components. Consider read this [section](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.servlet), depending the version of Servlet that you are using it could be little bit different.